# How do you install profiling libraries in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, profiling, cabal

After running

```
ghc --make -prof -fprof-auto -rtsopts encode.hs
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Failed to load interface for ‘Data.Text’
Perhaps you haven't installed the profiling libraries for package ‘text-1.2.5.0’?
Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
```

I've tried this:

```
cabal install -p text --reinstall
```

As suggested here:

[https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/9.0.1/docs/html/users_guide/profiling.html](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/9.0.1/docs/html/users_guide/profiling.html)

My version of ghc is 8.0.2 so maybe I should be seeing some other documentation though.

Comment: Is there a reason you're invoking `ghc` directly instead of using a tool like `cabal` or `stack` to build `encode.hs`? If not, I'll be happy to write up an answer describing how this would be done with `cabal`.

Comment: no specific reason, it was just how I kne whow to do it

Answer (score 3):

One way would be to make a `cabal` package with an executable whose `main-is` was `encode.hs`. That done, you would run

```
cabal configure --enable-profiling --profiling-detail toplevel-functions
```

once; subsequent `cabal build` commands and similar should just do the right thing. One thing worth noting, though, is that some care is required to pass RTS options to the right program when using `cabal`. The recipe looks like:

```
cabal run exe:encode -- +RTS ... -RTS
```

Any `+RTS`/`-RTS` blocks that appear before the `--` will go to `cabal`; those after will go to your program.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm just not sure how to make a cabal package, so I don't know how to try your solution.

Comment: @Chebi Make a new directory, put `encode.hs` in it, and run `cabal init`. You may have to add dependencies to the `build-depends` stanza afterwards, but I think it should auto-detect `encode.hs` and mark it as an executable.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `stack` then you can do

```
stack build --profile
```

Reference: https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/2285